Can GCC use LTO to optimize MIPS load/store instruction pairs for linker-defined addresses that are close together
Problem Statement
Assume 32-bit MIPS I, and code written in C for an embedded system.
When loading from an externally defined variable (extern int myVar;) that comes from a symbol defined in a linker script (myVar = 0x80190000;), GCC will emit a blank lui/lw instruction pair in the object file, which the linker fills in later. This is expected since you need at least a pair of instructions to guarantee a load/store of any arbitrary address.
If you have many linker-defined symbols that all have the same upper 16-bits (0x8019XXXX), you can optimize access to those symbols within a function by loading the upper bits once, then each access to a symbol with the same prefix can be done with a single instruction:
lui a0,0x8019
lw  s0,20(a0)
lw  s1,300(a0)
lw  s2,1415(a0)
...

GCC is smart enough to perform this kind of optimization for symbols it knows about in advance, such as addresses defined in a header file. However, since GCC does not know about symbol locality for linker-defined symbols, the object file that it emits still has two instructions allocated for each load. I learned about LTO recently and it looked like it was exactly the tool to solve this problem: an optimization pass that happens when the locality of the symbols is known.
I added -flto -fuse-linker-plugin to my GCC command line, but it made no difference to the output. Every linker-defined symbol was still allocated two instructions.
Question
Can the LTO features of the GCC toolchain be used to solve this problem? My assumption is that LTO would see the opportunity to reduce load/store instruction pairs to single instructions when they shared a common prefix, but that seemingly does not happen. Perhaps I just don't have the correct arguments supplied?
I have been light on the specifics of my setup because I am not sure this is even something that LTO can accomplish at all, regardless of how carefully I have my makefile set up. Furthermore, I actually have a solution to this problem already: moving all of the linker-defined symbols into a header file as constant pointers. I'm more interested in if LTO can accomplish this feat rather than looking for any way to solve the problem.
Note that this is very similar to the problem that global-pointer optimization solves. In this case though, the compiler does not have control over the symbols' location.
Here's my GCC invocation, just in case:
gcc -Wall -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -fno-pic -nostdlib
    -fsigned-char -fshort-enums -fno-strict-overflow -march=r3000 -mabi=32 -mfp32
    -mno-mt -mno-llsc -mno-abicalls -mno-check-zero-division
    -G0 -mno-gpopt -lgcc -Os -DNDEBUG -T main.ld -o output.elf main.c


Are you talking about linker relaxation?  If so, RISC V has it but I don't know about MIPS,

Linker relaxation does sound pretty close to what I am looking for; the docs I found for RISC V linker relaxation even call out the dual instruction thing explicitly. Looking through GCC MIPS documentation though, it seems like only function call relocations get the treatment that I'm looking for. Other symbols only seem to get optimized if they are gp-relative.
